# Recursively saving web pages

Tags: internet

Is it possible to recursively save all pages on the web which depend on a particular page? Or do I always need to save them one by one?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I've needed this I've found [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) to be effective, easy to use, and fairly comprehensive on the options.

> HTTrack is a free (GPL, libre/free software) and easy-to-use offline browser utility.
>
> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer. HTTrack arranges the original site's relative link-structure. Simply open a page of the "mirrored" website in your browser, and you can browse the site from link to link, as if you were viewing it online. HTTrack can also update an existing mirrored site, and resume interrupted downloads. HTTrack is fully configurable, and has an integrated help system.
>
> WinHTTrack is the Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Seven release of HTTrack, and WebHTTrack the Linux/Unix/BSD release.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
wget -m http://www.example.com/
```

More information can be find with `man wget`:

```
-m --mirror Turn on options suitable for mirroring.
            This option turns on recursion and time-stamping,
            sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP directory listings.
            It is currently equivalent to -r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing.
```

Comment: I'm a beginner, can You explain it?

Comment: From the man page:
       -m
       --mirror
           Turn on options suitable for mirroring.  This option turns on
           recursion and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and
           keeps FTP directory listings.  It is currently equivalent to -r -N
           -l inf --no-remove-listing.

Comment: `wget` is a Linux / Unix program for downloading web pages.

Comment: @sleske: It does have some very good windows ports, however.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by using software that can crawl the page. I like using Free Download Manager's HTML spider that can download a page and you can specify how many levels of depth you want it to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes It's possible by using some tools designed for this pupose like:
Internet Download Manager(IDM) and Offline Explorer.
with these tools you can even download the whole website for offline exploring.or just to download the one page with dependent links.