# Saving entire hiearchy of web pages and contents

Tags: html, kindle, epub, mobi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recursively saving web pages](https://superuser.com/questions/162665/recursively-saving-web-pages)

I remember I had found a  utility a while back that basically enabled me to save an entire hierachy of webpages as a single "book". I was wondering if anyone remembered said utility, and knew if there were any utilities that would perform this task, but convert the entire hierachy of pages to epub or mobi files for my kindle. Here is my target website:

http://newdata.box.sk/bx/c/index.htm

Comment: What you are trying to do is called spidering